# Canvas toDataURL return empty

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to export SVG element as image blob using Canvas. When i try to invoke canvas.toDataURL("image/png") it returns empty string. I am not able to figure out why this happens.

```
const svg: Node = document.getElementById("flowchart-container").children[0];
var icanvas = document.getElementById("stage");
const ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = icanvas.getContext("2d");
var width = (svg as HTMLElement).clientWidth;
var height = (svg as HTMLElement).clientHeight;
const image: HTMLImageElement = document.createElement("img");
image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
const imageBlob: Blob = new Blob(
  [new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg)],
  {
    type: "image/svg+xml",
  }
);
const blobUrl: string = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob);
image.src = blobUrl ;
image.onload = (): void => {
  //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl);
  try {
    const imageData: string = icanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    const imageFileToBeExported: Blob | File = this.dataURLtoFile(
      imageData,
      "flowchart.png"
    );
    promiseResolve(imageFileToBeExported);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Failed to Create Image');
    console.log(error);
    promiseReject(error);
  }
};
```

Above code goes inside the createSVG method. Caller is the display method.

```
    public createSVG(
        promiseResolve: (data: File | Blob) => void,
        promiseReject: (error: unknown) => void
        ): void {
        //Code for Creating File
    }

public async getImage() :Promise<any>{
    let imageBlob: File | Blob;
    try {
        imageBlob = await generateImageAsynchronously();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Failed to create Image');
    }
}

public generateImageAsynchronously(): Promise<File | Blob> {
    return new Promise(
      (
        resolver: (data: File | Blob) => void,
        reject: (error: unknown) => void
      ): void => {
        this.createSVG(resolver, reject);
      }
    );
}
```

Finally the call invoked from below method

```
public display(){
    this.getImage().then(response => {
      console.log('Resolving Promise');
      this.imageBlob = response;
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a common issue when using .onload, basically you're returning the promise before the data is processed.
You can try wrapping it in a async function like this

```
async function waitForloading(){
let waitForLoad = await processImage()
return waitForLoad
}

function processImage(){
return new Promise(function(promiseResolve,promiseReject){
const svg: Node = document.getElementById("flowchart-container").children[0];
var icanvas = document.getElementById("stage");
const ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = icanvas.getContext("2d");
var width = (svg as HTMLElement).clientWidth;
var height = (svg as HTMLElement).clientHeight;
const image: HTMLImageElement = document.createElement("img");
image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
const imageBlob: Blob = new Blob(
  [new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg)],
  {
    type: "image/svg+xml",
  }
);
const blobUrl: string = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob);
image.src = blobUrl ;
image.onload = (): void => {
  //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl);
  try {
    const imageData: string = icanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    const imageFileToBeExported: Blob | File = this.dataURLtoFile(
      imageData,
      "flowchart.png"
    );
    promiseResolve(imageFileToBeExported);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Failed to Create Image');
    console.log(error);
    promiseReject(error);
  }
};
)}
}
```

Comment: Its not working even with async. When i tried to log the output of icanvas.toDataURL("image/png") i get - ,

Comment: It was due to Foreign objects present inside the SVG element which caused cross origin issue.